# What all do I need in my .htaccess, such as permissions, etc

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions, root

I've got a `.htaccess` file at the root directory of my website, and I've made sure `.htaccess` *is* the extension, not `.htaccess.txt`. I'm trying to clean up my .php urls, and even after looking at all the other questions about this, it is not working.

I'm quite strongly sure that the code for removing the extension is correct, so it makes me wonder if there is other code that I need inside the `.htaccess` for permissions or something like that. Thanks for any answers, and *please* don't mark this as `duplicate`... I've searched for hours on Stack Overflow, SitePoint, and all the other websites.

Here is the *only* code inside my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Just to make sure it's clear, I want the urls:

```
website.com/about.php
website.com/home.php
website.com/blog.php
```

to look like

```
website.com/about
website.com/home
website.com/blog
```

It should remove `.php` from **ALL** .php files in all directories for my website.

Comment: What are you expecting that rewrite rule to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

you actually want

```
RewriteEngine On

#if the requested file doesn't exist on server filesystem
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

#AND if the file with php extension exists. Just an extra check
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 

#AND if the request isn't for domain root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\.php?r=1 [L]

#redirect all urls ending with .php to "clean" URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)r=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  /$1? [L,R=301]
```

It will not make `website.com/about.php` look like `website.com/about` but it will display `website.com/about.php` if user visits `website.com/about`.

Comment: That's now what I'm looking for. I don't want it to show the `.php` extension

Comment: did you try the rewrite rule?

Comment: I want it to show `website.com/about` even if they type `website.com/about.php`, not the other way around.